# How to display an images link stored in an xml document using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

If I have an image address in XML tags, how do I display the image in my HTML using javascript? If it's possible.

Here's the XML

```
<countries>
<country region="north-america">
    <name>USA</name>
    <totalcases>88,822,018</totalcases>
    <activecases>3,247,166</activecases>
    <seriouscases>3,117</seriouscases>
    <totalrecoverd>84,534,008</totalrecoverd>
    <deaths>1,040,844</deaths>
    <casespermill>265,263</casespermill>
    <flag>https://cdn.britannica.com/33/4833-004-828A9A84/Flag-United-States-of-America.jpg</flag>
</country>
</countries>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onload = function () {
                let image = xhr.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('flag')[0].childNodes[0];

                document.body.append(image.data);
                console.log(image);
            };

            xhr.onerror = function () {
                console.log('Error while getting XML.');
            };

            xhr.open('GET', 'Folder/data.xml'); //<<==== correct path to your XML file
            xhr.responseType = 'document';
            xhr.send();
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Paulo Fernando, thanks for the answer but your solution isn't working

Comment: What's the error? I tested in visual studio code, having the html and your xlm in the same folder

Comment: It says, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNodes')
    at xhr.onload

Comment: I was able to reproduce your error by informing an incorrect path to the XML file, I edited my answer, put the correct path or link in 'Folder/data.xml'